# Sprite Kit odd background behavior, different on simulator than device

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, background-process

When my sprite kit game goes to the background, I have a NSNotification to pause the game and the background music.  The notifications are..

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

The two selector methods indicated are..

```
- (void)willEnterForeground
{
SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.scene.paused = NO;
[[SKTAudio sharedInstance] resumeBackgroundMusic];
}

- (void)willEnterBackground
{
SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.scene.paused = YES;
[[SKTAudio sharedInstance] pauseBackgroundMusic];
}
```

The SKTAudio sharedInstance is from Ray Wenderlich's tutorial and stops the AVAudioSession and restarts it with play and pause.  I put breakpoints on all the lines in the selector methods and each one is performed while using the simulator.  Everything works as planned, my app pauses along with the music when the App goes to the background.  When I bring it back, the music starts back up and the game continues where it left off just as it should.

The problem arises when I play the game just on the iPhone, not through Xcode.  When I just play the game normally, and I have the app go to the background, upon return, it takes me to my opening screen and not the game like it does in the simulator.  Am I missing something?  Why would it behave differently on the phone as to the simulator.  Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the previous question answered yesterday and the link that solved my problem...

[Handling interruptions in Sprite Kit - can't get sound effects via [SKAction playSoundFileNamed: to work after interruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978547/handling-interruptions-in-sprite-kit-cant-get-sound-effects-via-skaction-pla)

I believe your problem is the AVAudioSession is still active when going into the background.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, with my SKTAudio I do stop and start the Session.  I have even taken the background sound out and the same problem persists.

Comment: I would suggest turning on breakpoints and all exceptions and see where in your code an error gets generated when it goes into the background.  As long as you have "application does not run in the background" set to NO in your info.plist then the reason its starting your app over is that its generating an error when moving to the background

Comment: I have set breakpoints, but while running Xcode, I get no errors.  All works as expected. It is not until I run it on the phone by itself that the restarting happens.  Also, I checked the plist, and I can't find an entry for "application does not run in the background"  Where did you find that?

Comment: Well, I was actually able to reproduce the behavior while the phone was connected and was able to use some back trace and found that the AVAudioSession was to blame.  Don't know why the breakpoints allowed the crash to not happen, but that is a question for another day!  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though!